# Return type for this function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

my function prototype is this.

```
int * f4(int parm);
```

my function looks like this

```
int * f4(int parm)
{
    return &parm + 1;  
}
```

Is my return type correct for this? because it isn't doing anything when I call the function.

this is my call

```
int *pointer1;
pointer1 = f4(319);
cout << pointer1 << endl;
```

it returns the address of the pointer, but I need it to return the value, but I can't seem to get it to work.

using

```
cout << *pointer << endl;
```

just displays 0

Comment: Do you want it to return 319+1?

Comment: What is "isn't doing anything" supposed to mean? It is very plainly *doing something*. (It's just doing something rather... pointless.)

Comment: Evaluating `*pointer` is undefined behaviour, since your function returns garbage.

Comment: If you want your function to return "value", why did you declare it to return a "pointer"? And what makes you think it "isn't doing anything"? It does exactly what you made it to do.

Comment: Do you understand what `&parm + 1` is really doing? You are incrementing the address of a local function parameter by 4 bytes and then returning that. If this was used in a context of a stl algorithm it would make some sense but it doesn't look like you're doing anything like that here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the object `parm` is local to that function. It's not legal to take and keep (i.e. return) a pointer to it after the function invocation ends.

In other words, `parm` "lives" while the function exists. When the function returns all its local objects  (such as `parm`) "die".

As `crush` notes in the comments, `pointer1` becomes an invalid pointer, also affectionately called a "dangling" pointer.

> so show the correct way to do it!!

As requested, there are a few ways to "correctly" do this:

- Return `parm + 1` directly, and change the return type of the function. It doesn't sound like you really need a pointer
- Take the parameter as a pointer (or reference, this is C++) and increment its pointed value. You can also return it if you so desire - returning it is valid since it comes from outside the function
- Add a static `static int sparm; sparm = parm + 1` and return a pointer to `sparm`. This will make your function non-reentrant but it will work: `static` objects don't die when the function invocation ends
- Allocate (ugh! don't!) some memory for a pointer and return that

---

Upon reading the code more carefully, it is quite clear that pointer is never valid. From the start it's one slot beyond the memory available as `parm`.

Comment: I actually like them not showing exactly how to do it. I want to learn it, not just be given the answer

Comment: @Hogan Done, I added some suggestions

Comment: @Hogan: That's a difficult thing to ask for, since it's unclear what the OP *wants*. Given that she's presented the desired signature, it's possible that something else is required, and just showing "something that's correct and does something" may not necessarily be useful.

Comment: @KerrekSB I just noticed the `&parm +1` thing. I understand less and less from this question.

Comment: @cnicutar: The OP is totally off the deep end if you ask me. The only "sane" answer seems to be `int * p = malloc(sizeof *p); if (p) *p = ++parm; return p;`, but I don't have the heart to suggest that.

Comment: lol, it is stupid to do it this way I understand that. I would never do it this way on my own. Do not ask me why my teacher is having it done this way. But I got it to work, without you all giving me the exact code. thanks @cnicutar

Answer (score 3):

Returning a pointer to a local variable is bad news.  `parm` is a function parameter, and so is local to `f4`.  You're returning a bad pointer to the caller and then trying to dereference it.  That will only end in tears.

Comment: The correct way to do what?  OP hasn't said what his intention is.